# Python- code block goes to the if but to the else block as well- Why?

Tags: python, if-statement

can someone told me why this code goes to the if block but even if I select one of the 3 options it goes to the else block as well?

```
elige = "diccionario"
dict = {1:"Emiliano", 2: "Grama", "Fastlaner": "Volviendo a programar"}
tupla = ("Lista", "Fija", "de","mie",1)
lista = ["sera","una","list"]
result = ""

if elige == "diccionary" :
    dict[2] = "que chor"
    result = dict
    print (result)

if elige == "Tuple" :
    result = tupla
    print ("he aqui tu tupla")
    print (result)

if elige == "list" :
    result = lista
    print(result)

else:
    print("no fue por ningun camino che")
    print(result)
```

Comment: The ``else`` block only "attaches" to the one preceding ``if``, not all of them. You might want to read up about ``elif``...

Comment: also note that [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) is a built-in. you should not overwrite any of those.

Answer (score 1):

If *any* in the chain of `if` statements passing should prevent the `else` from executing, *all* but the first `if` should be an `elif` to tie the blocks together:

```
if elige == "diccionary":
    ...
elif elige == "Tuple":  # elif ties it to preceding if
    ...
elif elige == "list":   # elif ties it to preceding if/elif
    ...
else:                   # Now tied to whole if/elif chain
    ...
```

Side-note: In your actual example, the `else` *should* execute; the `if` tests for `"diccionary"`, but `elige` is `"diccionario"`. That said, the `else` as you wrote it would have executed for any `elige` but `"list"`, which was almost certainly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the 2nd and 3rd ifs for elif like this:

```
elif elige == "Tuple" :
    result = tupla
    print ("he aqui tu tupla")
    print (result)
```

Otherwise the else clause belongs only to the 3rd if, which is not what you want

Answer (score 0):

None of your if statements are true, so we proceed to the else. I would do the whole thing like this.

```
elige = "diccionario"
dict = {1:"Emiliano", 2: "Grama", "Fastlaner": "Volviendo a programar"}
tupla = ("Lista", "Fija", "de","mie",1)
lista = ["sera","una","list"]
result = ""

if elige == "diccionary" :
    dict[2] = "que chor"
    result = dict
    print (result)

elif elige == "Tuple" :
    result = tupla
    print ("he aqui tu tupla")
    print (result)

elif elige == "list" :
    result = lista
    print(result)

else:
    print("no fue por ningun camino che")
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The **else** block is only part of the last **if statement**

I think you probably want this:

```
if elige == "diccionary":
    dict[2] = "que chor"
    result = dict
    print (result)

elif elige == "Tuple":
    result = tupla
    print ("he aqui tu tupla")
    print (result)

elif elige == "list":
    result = lista
    print(result)

else:
    print("no fue por ningun camino che")
    print(result)
```